# Why is my Web page resposnive only in Responsive Design View but not in browser?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am testing my webpage using the Responsive Design View tool and everything works just fine (the window is responsive and all).

When I try to do the same thing in Chrome, IE or even Mozilla, nothing happens - the page becomes unresponsive. Any ideas why is this happening?

**CSS**:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width :  768px) {

  .main_container {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
  }

  #header {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: tomato;
  }

  #stanga {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
  }

  .dreapta {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
  }

  footer {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    clear: both;
  }
} 

@media screen and (min-device-width : 767px) and (max-device-width :  1200px) {

  .main_container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
  }

  #header {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: tomato;
  }

  #stanga {
    width: 650px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
  }

  .dreapta {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
  }

  footer {
    height: 150px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: black;
    clear: both;
  }
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1200px) {

  .main_container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
  }

  #stanga {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
  }

  .dreapta {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
  }

  footer {
    height: 150px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: black;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are your codes??

Comment: What exactly in my code could make you understand the problem (so I know what to post)? It's pretty long.

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us the problem.

Comment: Leaving aside the "design": https://jsfiddle.net/Cilvako/eermqtok/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between min-width and min-device-width.  Use min-width for desktops.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

The "min-device-width" setting would refer to the width of the device.  The "min-width" attribute would refer to the width of the browser.

```
@media screen and (min-width : 767px) and (max-width :  1200px)
```

note: It appears that you do have collisions happening right at 768px and also at 480px.  I assume it's unintentional, so you may want to fix that also.

I edited your fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/8dt44c5b/

Comment: Yes, now it's working, thx a lot for your help. I am still trying to make sense of these media queries starting with basic examples. Can you tell me what do you mean with "collisions happening right at 768px and also at 480px"? It means that something there is overwriting, no?

Comment: if min is 480 on one media query and max is 480 on another media query then at 480, both media queries will fire.  The last media query that matches may overwrite some of the things in previous media queries.  This may or may not be problematic.